# print_r return 1 althought no record was saved

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have some method to save record including user token and email like this:

```
public function saveResetToken($email, $resetToken)
    {
        try {

            $conn = Database::getConnection();
            // Connect and create the PDO object
            $conn->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');      // Sets encoding UTF-8
            // Define and prepare an INSERT statement
            $sql = 'UPDATE users SET reset_token=:token WHERE email =:email limit 1';
            $stmt =$conn->prepare($sql);

            // Adds value with bindParam
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':token', $resetToken,PDO::PARAM_STR );

            if ($stmt->rowCount()===1){   

                $conn = null;        // Disconnect
                return true;

            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            include('../views/error.php');
            include('../views/admin/includes/footer.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
```

when i use print_r $stmt->rowCount() it return '1', but when check at my reset_token i find no data. so what wrong in my code?

Comment: You should be running `$stmt->execute();` after `...->bindParam(...);` to update the database. Are you saying `$resetToken` is empty? Where are you doing this `print_r`? If it has "no data" in the entire function you must be passing it in wrong. Let me know if this answers your question. I am trying to find more info before making an answer.

Comment: @DutGRIFF you right, i'm so careless when i copy paste my code i overwrite execute() but earlier why it return 1 when i user Print_r ($user->saveResetToken($email, $activasion)? :D

Comment: Please update the code in your question. I don't see a `print_r($user->saveResetToken($email, $activasion)` so I can't tell you why it is returning 1. Unless you are wondering why the whole function returns 1.

Comment: i user print_r outside a class. i have reset.php file and this file in user.class.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon some investigation I realized you are asking why this function is returning `1` when you are expecting `true`. When your function returns true it actually returns a 1. So it will return `1` but if you do `if($user->saveResetToken($email, $activation)) print('this is true')` you can see this is actually evaluating to true.

Try this:

```
function myFunc() {
  return true;
}
echo myFunc(); // output: 1
echo myFunc()==true; // output: 1
echo myFunc()==1; // output: 1
echo myFunc()===true; // output: 1
echo myFunc()===1; // output: 1
```

In php `true` actually means not zero.

Here are the values that are considered false from the docs:

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> `the boolean FALSE itself
>   the integer 0 (zero)
>   the float 0.0 (zero)
>   the empty string, and the string "0"
>   an array with zero elements
>   an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
>   the special type NULL (including unset variables)
>   SimpleXML objects created from empty tags`

Check out the [php docs on booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) for more information.

As for the record not being saved you must use the `->execute()` on the query as mentioned in my comment.